# How can I test the antivirus program I am developing?

Tags: antivirus, virus

I need to develop antivirus software for Windows. Where can I download viruses or virus-like programs to test it with?

Comment: I gotta say, if you don't already know where to find virus samples, trying to write an antivirus program seems very premature.

Comment: @jball: It's quite literally a solution looking for a problem.

Comment: This is a question on obtaining and installing software - therefore, it belongs on SU

Comment: @Shog9 - I hope keling is not naive enough to try and run a virus after obtaining it...

Comment: @Shog9: Looks to me like it's a question on obtaining a test corpus for antivirus development. Sounds more like SO material than SU.

Comment: @mmyers: I donno... Obtaining Photoshop to draw a splash screen is technically dev-related as well, but practically speaking both are better suited for SU.

Comment: Why are you trying to write your own AV software? What is wrong with the hundreds of existing AV solutions out there? Specifically ClamWin is GPL licensed - why don't you join that project?

Comment: @Peter: actually, there's money to be had in selling even a small AV package. However, it isn't actually necessary for such a thing to be able to *detect viruses*.

Answer (score 10):

The [EICAR test file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file) is a good start, as it is an example of a self modifying program -- something that malware usually does.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the many fake antimalware programs out there. Some SO scrapers "featured" one recently, links are in meta stack overflow.

Possibly, make sure you try them in a virtual machine disconnected from the internet. ;)